# Getting an error while trying to insert multiple values at once. Why is that?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

While trying to insert multiple values into the table, I get a syntax error.I created table named `arts` by the following query :

```
CREATE TABLE arts( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , subdir VARCHAR (255), PRIMARY KEY(id));
```

and the insert query I am using is :

```
INSERT INTO TABLE arts (id,subdir) VALUES('Aesthetics','Literature');
```

What could be the reason for the error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO arts (subdir) VALUES('Aesthetics'),('Literature');
```

Multiple records are seperated with `( )`. Without it, like in your case, it is trying to insert one record with two fields (not counting auto increment et cetera).

Also notice that I've removed the `id`, since you don't wanna insert it (it's `AUTO_INCREMENT` after all, so it does that for you).

Comment: In which of the two queries?

Comment: the one you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You have your id set as INT, INT is for numbers only, you are trying to insert text into a integer, it will never work. You also have id set as auto increment, change id to varchar and it will work. You could try this:

```
CREATE TABLE arts( id VARCHAR (255) , subdir VARCHAR (255), PRIMARY KEY(id));
INSERT INTO TABLE arts VALUES('Aesthetics','Literature');
```

Also you don't need to tell it to insert into id and subdir. If you have the values in order, it will insert into them. Good luck!

Comment: I think the OP is trying to insert multiple rows, not multiple values in 1 row.

Comment: When you're using mysql, you don't need to define which rows your inserting to, whenever you have values() each '' is a different row, if you have '','' it will insert into two rows. Example, if your first  row is 1 and your second row is 2, if you do `INSERT INTO TABLE arts VALUES('1','2');`, you don't need to define the rows because you're inserting "1" into the first row and "2" into the second row. I do this all the time and it always works. But id is set as INT and a string is being inserted into it, it wouldn't work. Integer = numbers

Answer (score 0):

Try this....
dont mention "id"

```
INSERT INTO TABLE arts (subdir) VALUES('Aesthetics','Literature');
```

Comment: The `id` is `AUTO_INCREMENT` so shouldn't be supplied.

Answer (score 0):

**INSERT** multiple values in table.

Create table

```
 CREATE TABLE table1(ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, field1 varchar(50),field2 varchar(50),field3 varchar(50));
```

method 1:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (field1,field2,field3) 
VALUES('AAA','1','AAA1'),('BBB','2','BBB2'),('CCC','3','CCC3')
```

method 2:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (field1,field2,field3) 
SELECT 'AAA','1','AAA1' UNION 
SELECT 'BBB','2','BBB2' UNION
SELECT 'CCC','3','CCC3'
```